# getting matching data from two table where date is compared with date range postgres

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, date-range, cartesian-product

I have 'order_history' and 'current_order' tables both has similar columns as mentioned below:
order_name, Consumer_name, order_date , Order_ amount

every time I get new orders and I have to find out overlapping orders and delete those duplicate from history table and then append current_table data but now this has been worst because my date is getting changed in current table so I have to consider +/- 14 days while comparing order_date and then delete it from history table
Please see sample table data 
---Current Order 
order_name| Consumer_name| order_date|order_amount
Wool  | Jhon  |  6/15/2017| 500
Wool  | Jhon  |  7/14/2017| 1000
Wool  | Jhon  |  8/13/2017| 800

---Order history
order_name| Consumer_name| order_date | order_amount
Wool  | Jhon  |  5/15/2017 | 1200
Wool  | Jhon  |  6/10/2017 | 500
Wool  | Jhon  |  7/8/2017 | 800

in above scenario I need to delete order rows for month of june and july ( 6/10/2017 and 7/8/2017) from history table and then need to appen current order table entries into history table.

I am using below query

```
select a.order_name, a.consumer_name, a.order_date , a.order_amount 
from  order_history a inner join current_order b 
on ( upper(a.order_name) = upper(b.order_name) and  
upper(a.consumer_name) = upper(b.consumer_name))
where
upper(a.order_name) = upper(b.order_name) and  
upper(a.consumer_name) = upper(b.consumer_name)
and  a.order_date -b.order_date <= 14 and a.order_date -b.order_date >= -14
```

but I am getting duplicate rows

can you please help me with this query. one solution can be a Cartesian product where each row will be compared with all rows of another table but this query will take huge amount of time due to data size is million rows

Comment: You have the duplicate criteria in your query, but that doesn't influence the results of course. It seems you sometimes have multiple records in current_order that match one record in order_history, so you get duplicate history records in your results, as you join them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ABS` to get the difference between the dates as a positive number. If you simply want to delete from the history table, use `EXISTS` to look up the current orders table.

```
delete
from order_history h
where exists
(
  select *
  from current_order c
  where c.order_name = h.order_name
    and c.consumer_name = h.consumer_name
    and abs(c.order_date - h.order_date) <= 14
);
```